# How can I read xml metadata from a Corel file with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, coreldraw, cdr

I don't understand how I can read tags, from a metadata.xml of a [cdr files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW#CDR_file_format). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Here is the file http://pastebin.com/bXwLN1FE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [DOMDocument](http://php.net/dom) oh PHP5

```
$xml  = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xml_data); // $xml_data is the contents of metadata.xml
$tags = $xml->getElementsByTagName(""); // put your tag name here.
foreach($tags as $tag){
   // further process the tags
}
```